# Use stage parameters to skip fields in Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, serverless-framework

Stage parameters in Serverless Framework are very useful to change stage-dependent fields, such as `apiKey:`. However, I'd like to use them to skip fields all together. Would this be possible?
As an example below (highly simplified) I'd like to have an API key for the `dev` stage, but no API key for the `v1` stage:

```
frameworkVersion: '3'

params:
  dev:
    name: 'dev'
    keyName: FooBarKey
  v1:
    name: 'v1'
    keyName: null

provider:
  name: aws
  apiGateway:
    apiKeys:
      - ${param:keyName}
```

Unfortunately the `null` in the `v1` stage does not allow for the `apiKeys` field to be skipped. Instead Serverless produces an error:

```
Cannot resolve variable at "provider.apiGateway.apiKeys.0": Value not found at "param" source
```

This makes sense, but I was wondering if there is any other way to achieve what I'm aiming for here.

Comment: I would recommend switching to serverless.ts from serverless.yml to have high customisability

Comment: using serverless.ts is an option, but I'd prefer to stick with serverless.yml. I was wondering if using a `default value` in `${param:keyName, default value}` could somehow be used to skip the field.